# How to append cell with multiple links to a Google Sheet

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I know how to append a cell with an image link to a Google Sheet.
I also know how to append multiple cells with an image link in each to a Google Sheet.

```js
async function addDataToSheet(data) {
    const auth = await authorize();
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, 
        range: 'Sheet1!A1:F',
        // valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        resource: {
            values: [data]

        }
    });
}
```

And, there is a way to add multiple image links in a single cell using `batchUpdate`.

```js
async function addDataToSheetHtml() {
    const auth = await authorize();
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });

    const html = `
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>sample <a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a> sample <a href="https://tanaikech.github.io/">link2</a> sample</td>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>`;

    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        requests: [{
            pasteData: {
                html: true,
                data: html,
                coordinate: {
                    sheetId: sheets.getSheetId(),  // Modified
                    rowIndex: sheets.getLastRow(),  // Modified
                    columnIndex: 0,
                },
            },
        },],
    })
}
```

But it appears that `batchUpdate` can't append to a sheet.

That wouldn't be a problem if there was a way to find that last cell on a sheet, but there seems not to be such a function.

Is there a way to **append** a cell that contains multiple clickable links to a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to append the value including multiple hyperlinks to the specific sheet using Sheets API with googleapis for Node.js.

#### Modification points:

- About `And, there is a way to add multiple image links in a single cell using batchUpdate.`, when I saw your showing script, I thought that `sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` cannot be used `pasteData`. In this case, it is required to use `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`. And, your request body is required to be modified, and `const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });` has no methods of `getSheetId()` and `getLastRow()`.
- In your situation, first, it is required to retrieve the row number of the last row of the sheet.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your Sheet name.
const sheetId = "0"; // Please set your Sheet ID.

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: auth });

// Retrieve last row number of the sheet.
const res1 = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range: sheetName,
});
const lastRow = res1.data.values.length;

// HTML table is appended to the sheet using pasteData.
const html = `
  <table>
      <tr>
      <td>sample <a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a> sample <a href="https://tanaikech.github.io/">link2</a> sample</td>
      <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a></td>
      </tr>
  </table>`;
await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    resource: {
      requests: [
        {
          pasteData: {
            html: true,
            data: html,
            coordinate: {
              sheetId: sheetId,
              rowIndex: lastRow,
              columnIndex: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }).catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

### Added:

When an HTML table is put to the cells using `PasteDataRequest`, unfortunately, it seems that the hyperlink style cannot be set. So, in this case, as another method, I would like to propose using `textFormatRuns`. When this is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your Sheet name.
const sheetId = "0"; // Please set your Sheet ID.

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: auth });

// Retrieve last row number of the sheet.
const res1 = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: sheetName});
const lastRow = res1.data.values ? res1.data.values.length : 0;

// I modified the below script.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = "0"; // Please set Sheet ID.

// Please set the text and the hyperlinks.
const obj = [
  [
    {
      stringValue: "sample link1 sample link2 sample",
      links: [
        { value: "link1", uri: "https://www.google.com/" },
        { value: "link2", uri: "https://tanaikech.github.io/" },
      ],
    },
    {
      stringValue: "link1",
      links: [{ value: "link1", uri: "https://www.google.com/" }],
    },
  ],
];

const requests = [
  {
    updateCells: {
      rows: obj.map((row) => ({
        values: row.map(({ stringValue, links }) => ({
          userEnteredValue: { stringValue },
          textFormatRuns: links.reduce((ar, { value, uri }) => {
            const temp = stringValue.indexOf(value);
            if (temp != -1) {
              ar.push({ startIndex: temp, format: { link: { uri } } });
              if (stringValue.length != temp + value.length) {
                ar.push({ startIndex: temp + value.length });
              }
            }
            return ar;
          }, []),
        })),
      })),
      range: { sheetId: sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: 0 },
      fields: "userEnteredValue,textFormatRuns",
    },
  },
];

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId, resource: { requests } }).catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

- When this script is run, the values of "sample link1 sample link2 sample" and "link1" are put to the columns "A" and "B". And, 2 hyperlinks are included in the column "A" and 1 hyperlink is included in the column "B". And, all hyperlinks have the hyperlink style. The sample output situation is as follows.

[image]

Comment: This isn't working. The first two links in the first `<td>` don't show up with links. 
The single link in the second `<td>` however works. It is added to second column, not into the same cell. 
Any idea how get this working?

Comment: Wait, I see that it works partially like you described here: https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/b18c0189a5d0266a849090fdbe6750a5
The links are not visible directly. But when hovering over the cell, they can be clicked as individual links. 
It's not perfect, but at least it is a workaround for now.
Maybe you should add this to your solution for others to understand and see that limitation.

Comment: @alev Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. In this case, `textFormatRuns` is used. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: After a bit of tweaking, I got it to work. I had to set the target cell for instance. Essentially it works now. Thanks !

Comment: @alev Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.