# How can I format a part of a Google sheets cell value using googleapis?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis to insert data. One of my cells should contain multiple links, let's say

```
https://foo
https://bar
```

This is easy to do manually and I can query manually antered data and see the formatting. With this:

```js
const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.get({
    spreadsheetId,
    ranges: ['Intro!A1'],
    includeGridData: true
})
```

I can see the data formatting in `res`; screenshot below of the data from debugging. Circled in red is the value of the cell, underlined in blue is the first link defined in `textFormatRuns`.

[image]

**This is what I tried** to test formatting. This successfully writes the `stringValue`, but the `textFormatRuns` does nothing

```js
{
  userEnteredValue: {
    stringValue: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP\nabcdefghijklmnop"
  },
  textFormatRuns: [
    {
      format: { bold: true, underline: true, link: { uri: "https://ddg.gg" } }
    },
    {
      format:{}, startIndex: 9,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. And, I cannot imagine your expected result from your bottom object. I apologize for this situation. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I actually just now found the solution, writing an answer now :) -- no need to apologize at all, this is a very very specific problem. To simplify it, let's say my Google sheets has a cell, for example `Intro!A1` that has the value of "foo bar baz". What I need to do is change each word into a different clickable link using the NPM package googleapis.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your question, for example, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74075867

Comment: @Tanaike Yes! Actually, that would have been very useful in debugging, in the end I created a very similar solution, I just had a mistake in the `fields` property. I did try to search for such a thing, but did not find that one. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was that my `UpdateCellsRequest` contained this part: `fields: 'userEnteredValue'` which was somehow blocking the formatting update. This is very strange to me.

Here is a final proof of concept request that actually works to insert text into a cell and format parts of the cell (typescript):

```js
async function writeTest(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth })
  const spreadsheetId = 'xxxx' // SPREADSHEET ID
  const sheetId = 111111111111 // WORKSHEET ID

  const requests: any = [
    {
      updateCells: {
        start: { sheetId, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0 },
        rows: [
          {
            values: [
              {
                userEnteredValue: {
                  stringValue: "the quick brown fox\nlorem ipsum dolor"
                },
                textFormatRuns: [
                  { startIndex: 3, format: { bold: true } },
                  { startIndex: 6, format: {} },
                  { startIndex: 9, format: { bold: true, link: { uri: "https://ddg.gg" } } },
                  { startIndex: 12, format: {} }
                ]
              }
            ],
          },
        ],
        fields: '*' // This was the critical thing that was wrong!
      },
    }
  ]

  await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: { requests }
  }, {})
}

authorize() // This provides authentication/authorization
  .then(writeTest)
```

Here is the result; note the bold formatting and clickable link

[image: Screenshot from Google Sheets]

Answer (score 0):

One bit to @Joel Peltonen answer: for each semantic part fields should include path, that is updated (or is fetched from API) i.e.:

```
fields: 'userEnteredValue,textFormatRuns'
```